# Seamless box-shadow for blurry effect

Tags: css

I am trying to make a div look like a white glowing circle with no edges. The css is achieved with:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* makes the div background circular */
  background: white;
  height: 275px;
  width: 275px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 220px 279px #fff;
  /* creates glow effect */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

When there is a problem it looks like this:

[image: Example]

The problem is that on some screens, there is a line separating the circle from the glow. I am trying to achieve a seamless glow without the circle. I have tried `filter:blur` but this is not an option since it blurs the logo image nested inside the div.

The problem is on [the landing page of this site](http://brietsparks.net/).

Comment: What screen / browser?

Comment: @jbarnett chrome on a wide computer screen, not sure the dimensions, just remember seeing the line

Comment: @bsapaka - I am assuming the problem you are referring to is the same as the screenshot I added?

Comment: @misterManSam yes misterManSam that is exactly the problem

Comment: This question should be re-opened. It is a bug that can be reproduced in Chrome (I reproduced it in Chrome 39). This question **does have** the desired behaviour ("I am trying to make a div look like a white glowing circle with no edges"), the specific problem ("on some screens, there is a line separating the circle from the glow"), the code to reproduce it and the problem statement is clear with the provided screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buggy rendering in Chrome seems to be caused by the `blur-radius` and is *hidden* by the `spread-radius`; it seems to only occur with large `blur-radius` values. Through trial and error you can use the `spread-radius` to cover up the bug.

It's not perfect, but this works:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 300px #FFF;
```

These are the changes that work on your site. Place the border radius and box shadow on the outer div to eliminate a gray ring.

```
#logo-outer {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 275px; /* increase width to match #logo */
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 300px #FFF; /* change the box shadow blur and spread */
}
#logo {
    height: 275px;
    width: 275px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
}
```

#### This is what it looks like in Chrome

[image: Improved]

#### Bug Workaround Example

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 140px 300px #fff;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This works, in all practical senses. Thanks ministermansam! The thing that did the job was adding the box-shadow (same color, #fff) to the outer div. I kept the inner box shadow as well. Following your suggestion, I adjusted the blur and spread outer div until it masked the line of the inner div. Kudos!