# Chrome Box-Shadow display error in combination with border-radius

Tags: css, google-chrome

I´m using chrome Version 39.0.2171.71m on windows 7. I get a strange box-shadow display bug in combination with border-radius:

http://jsfiddle.net/54tLcje5/

```
HTML:
<div id="layer_content_wrapper">
</div>

CSS:
body {
    background-color: black;
}

#layer_content_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background-color: white;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    top: 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 300px 100px red;
}
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yEQFlo1.png]

Is there a workaround? Am I doing something wrong?

The display error did not occur rughly 3 Months ago...it has to have something to do with something which has changed in chrome. I had a page running for almost 2 years with this box-shadow until the error came up.

Thank you...

Comment: This would be a possible workaround, but it is not what I want and painful in the environment i`m going to use it.

Comment: I can confirm that with Chrome 38 on windows 7 it is working ok. So definitely is a bug introduced in v 39

Comment: I've come across this bug before. The trick is to reduce the spread of the `blur-radius` in your example `box-shadow: 0px 0px 200px 100px red;` seems to work fine with only a small change in look. [This was a solution of mine to the same problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27163606/2930477)

Comment: misterManSam: Thank you, it is not a solution, but I can work with it. Has this bug been reported to the Chrome developers?

Comment: I added it to the chromium issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=442335

Answer (score 0):

try using this css:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 100px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
```

where horizontal and vertical length is 0px, Blur radius from 300px to 140px, spear radius 100px and color rgba (with alpha channel to 0.6) for tricks the problem on chrome and have the same result like other browser

you can use this for cross browser:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 100px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 100px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 100px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation, please?