# border-radius with box-shadow inset pixelized / rugged

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

If you can't see this problem then please try take a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNjVaK), here you should see what I mean.

I've tried several ways to fix it. Below in comments you can see one of them. Still it seems to render 1px rugged border **between** proper **border** and **dropped shadow**.

If it depends on browser renderer then is it a bug?
How to fix it properly for all **modern** browsers.

```css
html{
  background-color: #554343;
}
div{
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0;      /* no result
  border-width: 2px;  // uncommented no result
  border-style: solid;// uncommented no result even with inset*/
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 150px, inset -1px -1px 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

EDIT: 
Tried also this way but without positive result:

```css
html{
  background-color: #554343;
}
.container{
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%; /* tried 49.5% but it's not acceptable */
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 150px #000, inset -1px -1px 150px #000;
}
.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe use vendor prefixes?

Comment: @Dmitriy Thanks, but it's wrong way http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Comment: you want result like code snippet...

Comment: just comment background-color: white;

Comment: Background needs to be white. Is seems, that box-shadow is in conflict with background color. Then I probably should use box-shadow at container and insert div with white background inside this container. But it still isn't easy to fix (same problem caused bg: white overflows ).

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=442335

Comment: @SergeyDenisov Thanks. It seems to be open bug. My question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463430/chrome-box-shadow-display-error-in-combination-with-border-radius

Comment: @SergeyDenisov Then would you like to answer my question with this link? Because correct answer is that it's unrepairable for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=442335

Seems like opened Chrome bug. I couldn't come up with a solution for your case. Please vote this issue on bug tracker if you want it to be fixed sooner!