# box-shadow glitch when interacting

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I have a vignette on my stock image created with box-shadow. It looks good, but sometimes when I press button that is on top of that vignette or when I select text then it dissapears only in the region of that selection which looks bad.

```
<div>
    <div class="stock-image flex-container">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="row column">
          <div>
            <h1 class="welcome">Connect with people</h1>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.stock-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32em;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(22, 156, 202,0.65), rgba(22, 156, 202,0.45)),#00A7E1 url(../../assets/img/home/stock-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30em 0.7em #000;
}
```

Sometimes when I select `Connect with people` it removes shadow inside the selected area and after deselecting it, the shadow is still missing.

Also I cannot just create vignette in photoshop, because the image is visible depending on device's screen size that user uses, so often only part of the image is visible.

**EDIT:**
As a workaround I used two linear-gradients:

```
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 65%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 85%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%)
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 65%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 85%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%)
```

It doesn't look as good as I would want, but I guess it's just a matter of tweeking parameters.

Comment: Are you using chrome or opera ?

Comment: I'm using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution for your problem but it seems to be linked with a known issue of chrome : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=442335
Also quoted in this post :
 [border-radius with box-shadow inset pixelized / rugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164827/border-radius-with-box-shadow-inset-pixelized-rugged?rq=1)

So the design your using is considered as a rendering bug.

Here you can compare the render of your code with different browser:
chrome : [http://imgur.com/Bu9b0hB](https://imgur.com/Bu9b0hB)
firefox : [http://imgur.com/ChJclHz](https://imgur.com/ChJclHz)
The firefox one is considered 'normal'.

Also your issue with the shadow and selections doesn't seems to appear on firefox.

To get an extendible image you might want to use 9-patch images, which is a technology used notably on android. I don't really know much about it...

Comment: These links you posted show exactly the issue I have. So I guess I have to find work around, without using box-shadow.

Comment: Well if you aim for the firefox rendering it looks a lot like a radial-gradient. Or maybe a combination of border-image.... I'm sorry I can't help more ^^

Answer (score 0):

You might try addressing Chrome directly in your CSS via  -webkit-box-shadow - e.g.:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px rgba(22,156,202,0.65);
box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px rgba(22,156,202,0.65);
```